How to Run Google Apps Script based on Tab in which the change was made?
I am following up to this question that was yesterday: How to Run onEdit/onChange function in Google Apps Script on Data pulled Dynamically using Query
The accepted answer worked for me. But now I'd like the script to handle three tabs in the same GSheet.
But I wnat it to only run in the tab in which change was made that is when a new row is added.
For some reason, the script only runs in the first tab.
I have tried changing it to something like this to no avail.
function myFunction(e) {
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
.
.
.
}

function myFunction(e) {
  var ss = e.range.getSheet();
.
.
.
}

Is there a way to run the script after detecting change in one tab only?

See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

You can test whether the edit took place in one of the sheets you are interested in like this:
function myFunction(e) {
  if (!e) throw new Error('Please do not run this function in the script editor window.');
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveRange();
  switch (sheet.getName()) {
    case 'Sheet1':
      doThing();
      break;
    case 'Sheet2':
      doThing();
      break;
    case 'Yet another sheet name':
      doAnotherThing();
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
}

See Sheet.getName() and switch.

Every single time, I get Sheet1...that's the problem.

The pattern I gave you lets you do a different thing depending on which sheet was modified. If the code you put in place of doThing() always looks at Sheet1, the problem is in that code, and you need to refer to sheet instead of Sheet1.

no you didn't understand ...sheet.getName() in switch (sheet.getName()) always returns Sheet1 no matter the change made in whichsheet/tab. So other cases are not executing except for the case 'Sheet1' I am using onChange trigger btw

The "on change" event object e does not have a range field to start with. Edited the answer to show how to get the sheet "on change". Please edit the question and add a Minimal, Reproducible Example.
